# Installation independent visual-C++ project properties

Tags: c++, visual-c++, project

Is there a way to adjust visual-C++ (MS VS 2010 EE) project properties in such a way, that the same .sln files can be built just in one click among different computers (on Windows, of course)? - so it will be possibly to upload visual-C++ projects to SVN server. Project uses some libraries (header and .lib files) with absolute (system dependent) path (e.g. boost) and it's own utils.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use environment variables in your project settings by enclosing them in $(). e.g. if your environment defines BOOST_INCLUDE:

```
set BOOST_INCLUDE=C:\boost\include\boost-1_45
```

then you can use `$(BOOST_INCLUDE)` in your settings to refer to the Boost include directory.

Comment: So, is there a way to automatically set environment variables right when building process starts? e.g. project use some exterior text file, where all variables are set, so everyone will be able to update from SVN, change just that one file, double-click on .sln file and then click "Build". Otherwise somebody will surely forget to set some variables using console.

Comment: I run the build from a batch file which tests for the existence of those variables before proceeding. You could set the environment variables that way, but if you have a shared build script which sets environment variables to a fixed location, it seems to defeat the purpose of using environment variables in the first place. For me, the best place to set them is in the "Environment Variables" options of the "System Properties" dialog. You can set it and forget it as long as your build process has some way of testing for them and alerting you if they're not set.

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio allows you to configure search directories for include files and libraries per system. You must agree with your colleages which folders should be made part of this scheme. Alternatively, you could use a set of predetermined environment variables and use paths relative to those.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio has some identifier like $(ProjectDir) that you can use in the project settings.

For example you could put a path like "$(ProjectDir)....\headers\boost\" in your include search path and it would work for multiple location of $(ProjectDir).

Other like $(ProjectName), $(ConfigurationName), $(IntDir) (Intermediate directory) can also be usefull.

I don't have a reference link for the moment.